# Angular Disable/Enable code blocks in ngOnInit()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, rxjs

I'm trying to decide the best design pattern to minimize the number of REST calls while implementing a 'save while typing feature'. I'll try to make it as general as possible.

In ngOnInit() I am including (keeping it as general as possible but dont worry there is a distinctUntilChanged() within the function to prevent it from spamming the REST endpoint):

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      if (this.formIsEditable) {
            this.inputField.valueChanges.subscribe(() => //do REST);
            }
}
```

However, formIsEditable is being set to true after the initialization of the component so it will never reach inside this code block. Is there a way in Angular to force an update when this boolean changes? Ideally when the boolean is set to false, it will prevent from sending a PUT to the Back End. If the boolean is true, it can send a PUT to the Back end.

Comment: What triggers the setting of `this.formIsEditable` to `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not simply :

```
this.inputField.valueChanges.subscribe(() =>
     if(this.formIsEditable){  //do REST }  
 );}
```

just don't forget to unsubscribe from this observable.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize RXJS `filter` operator, to filter values emitted while `this.formIsEditable` is set to false, as demonstrated below:

```
this.inputField.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    filter(_ => this.formIsEditable) 
  )
  .subscribe(() => //do REST);
```